# ActiveRecord query w/ check for empty field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am generating the condition for an ActiveRecord where as follows:

```
  query = {:status => status}

  if (limit)
    query[:limit] = @vals['limit'].to_i
  end

  if (offset && limit)
    query[:offset] = (offset - 1) * limit
  end

  rows = Review.all(query)
```

This works just fine.  I filter on 'status' of a review and I fill in limit and offset if passed in.  Problem is now that I need to add a check for 'not null' on the reviews content field.
I.E.
AND review.content != '' && review.content != nil

I have read you can do something like

```
Review.were("review <> ''")
```

Which by itself works but I am not sure how to incorporate that into my above command.  Or change the above command to work with a where statement rather than an 'all' statement.

Comment: Try this Review.where(query).where(("review <> ''")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write that code something like

```
query = Review.where("status = ?", status).where("review <> '' AND review IS NOT NULL")

if limit.present?
  query = query.limit(limit) 
  if offset.present?
    query = query.offset((offset - 1) * limit)
  end
end

rows = query.all
```

rails query object does lazy evaluation, so you can build up the query, no sql is issued to the database until you begin to iterate over the rows

alternate to `.where("review <> '' AND review IS NOT NULL")`

`.where("COALESCE(review, '') <> ''")`